# How to prevent std::function to bool conversion in c++ function overloading?

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading

How to prevent `std::function` to `bool` conversion in C++ function overloading?
such as

```cpp
class Object final {
    
public:
    Object(bool boolean) : type_(22)  {}  //#1
    Object(const std::function<int(int*, int)>  value) : type_(11) {}  //#2
    
    int rettype() { return type_; };
    
private:
    int type_;
};


int Println(int *args, int nargs) {
  printf("Println\n");
  return 0;
}

int main() {
    cout << Object(Println).rettype() << endl; // 22
    cout << Object(std::function<int(int*, int)>(Println)).rettype() << endl; // 11
}
```

I want to call **#2** through `Object(Println)` instead of `Object(std::function<int(int*, int)>(Println))`，but the result is that **#1** is called

How should I achieve this?

Comment: Aside: you might consider marking either or both constructors `explicit` unless you want explicit conversions from `bool` and `std::function` to `Object`. It won't solve the problem though.

Comment: Does it need to be `std::function`? Can you accept function pointer?

Comment: The type of the expression seems to be a perfect match for the overloaded function parameter. That's why that overload is chosen. That's what the rules of C++ specify. The End.

Comment: with template : https://wandbox.org/permlink/0eMXkH1l8HzbdfC0

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: No, it's not a "perfect" match, it has a non-empty conversion sequence. This is important, because it means you can add a better overload.

Comment: @FLAG: Quick check: do you intentionally exclude C++14, C++17 and C++20 ? C++11 is getting quite old by now.

Comment: Your question does not match your code. The conversion you are trying to avoid is a function pointer to `bool`, not `std::function` to `bool`. The conversion you want is function pointer to `std::function`. Nowhere does a conversion from `std::function` to `bool` enter the picture.

Comment: This is an implicit boolean conversion `([conv.bool])` that converts a prvalue of type `int(*)(int*, int)` to a prvalue of type `bool`. You can't just ignore this conversion

Comment: @FLAG Congratulation for such a great first question on StackOverflow. This contrasts with the too many dump questions coming from new comers.

Answer (score 12):

The modern C++ solution here would be
`Object::Object(std::invocable<int*, int> auto f)`

You don't care exactly what the type of f is - that's clear from the fact that you consider `std::function<int(int*, int)>` and `int(*)(int*, int)>` interchangeable. `std::invocable` is slightly more general than that: it says anything callable is also OK. A lambda would also work.

Comment: You also care about the return type, you need it to be usable (either exactly int or convertible to int). I feel like there should be such a concept, but I don't see one on a quick look at the [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts) . Do you know if there is one?

Comment: @bolov: I think you'd need a `requires std::convertible_to_v<int, decltype(f(nullptr, 0))>` or something like that.

Comment: @bolov Isn't that `invoke_result` (`result_of` in C++11)?

Comment: Yes, and to be generic you would need `requires std::convertible_to_v<int, decltype(f(std::declval<int*>(), std::declval<int>()))>` and that's not pretty at all. I was hoping something like `callable_like<int (int*, int)>` or something like that.

Comment: @Nelfeal: Good point - `requires std::convertible_to_v<int, std::invoke_result_t<f, int*, int>>`

Comment: @Nelfeal oh yeah, that's very close.

Comment: You could make your own type trait `callable_like`.

Comment: @Nelfeal yes, of course. I jest get irked when basic functionality is missing from the standard library.

Comment: There’s `std::is_invocable_r` to check the return type and the argument types conveniently.

Answer (score 2):

Why not a templated constructor which requires that the passed type is convertible to the desired function type?

```cpp
    template<typename F,
             typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<F, std::function<int(int*, int)>>::value, bool>::type = true>
    Object(const F&) : type_(11) {}
```

([Works with `-std=c++11`.](https://godbolt.org/z/vnT95shza))

The advantage is that you don't even have to truly have any `std::function` object at run time. You simply check at compile time that it could be converted to it, but then you use the callable as it is, being it a function pointer, a lambda, or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding a function pointer constructor?

```
Object(int (*value)(int*, int)) : Object(std::function<int(int*, int)>(value)) {}
```

You can also alias the function type:

```
using FunctionType = int (*)(int*, int);
Object(FunctionType value) : Object(std::function<int(int*, int)>(value)) {}
```

Comment: `std::function<int(int*, int)>` also accepts other function types. So to not lose that generality I would template the return and parameter types.

Comment: @user17732522 Not sure what you mean, feel free to edit.

Comment: `std::function<int(int*, int)>` could also be constructed from e.g. a pointer to a function `long f(void*, int)` because `long` can be implicitly converted to `int` and `int*` can be implicitly converted to `void*`. Your overload doesn't capture such cases.

Answer (score 1):

Check compiler warnings

> warning: the address of 'int Println(int*, int)' will never be NULL
> [-Waddress]

It means that function pointer automatically auto converting the `boolean` integral type.

To prevent this you can handle function pointer type by additional type deduction specifier.
std::function is a functional object e.g. functor, not a raw C function pointer and simply have a [converting constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor)

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Object final {

public:
    explicit Object(bool boolean) : type_(22)  {}  //#1
    explicit Object(int(*)(int*,int)) : type_(11) {}
    explicit Object(const std::function<int(int*, int)>&  value) : type_(11) {}  //#2

    int rettype() { return type_; };

private:
    int type_;
};

int Println(int *args, int nargs)
{
  std::cout << "Println" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

struct PrintLine
{
    int operator()(int*, int)
    {
        std::cout << "PrintLine" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    std::cout << Object(Println).rettype() << std::endl; // 11
    PrintLine pl;
    std::cout << Object(pl).rettype() << std::endl; // 11
    std::cout << Object(1).rettype() << std::endl; // 22
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one constructor, but template and select what you want to do inside

```
template<class T>
Object(T t) {
    if( std::is_same_v<T,bool>::value )
    {
        type_ = 22;
    }
    else
    {
        type_ = 11;
    }
}
```

demo 17+ : https://wandbox.org/permlink/0eMXkH1l8HzbdfC0 
demo 11  : https://wandbox.org/permlink/rOP4JRAP2Ywb1osf 
demo 11 in member initializer list : https://wandbox.org/permlink/6QDD4Vdo9TaqU4fT

It's only a POC, you may want check if the type is a type you want and fail if it's not what you expect.

Comment: The question is tagged C++11.

Comment: true, will update

Comment: Moving initialization out of the member initialization list (into the constructor body) looks like a step backwards.

Comment: you can make an helper function who do what I did here and call it in the list. Didn't do it for readability purpose

Comment: @JaMiT updated, lambda or function is matter of style